# For which values of $a$ does $||x^2-16|-7|-2a=0$ have 3 roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the equation:
$$||x^2-16|-7|-2a=0$$
Please help solve this.
For which $a$ does the equation have 3 roots?

Comment: Draw the picture of the graph $y=||x^2-16|-7|$, then the answer will come out by itself.

Comment: in that way found the answer is 9/2 . But I can't solve this without the graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Api, first, use the definition of absolute value.

$||x^2-16|-7|-2a=0$ implies that two cases:

1) $|x^2-16|-7=2a$

This equation gives us $a=\frac{x^2-23}{2} $ and $a=\frac{x^2-9}{2}$.

2) $|x^2-16|-7=-2a$

Again, this equation gives us $a=\frac{23-x^2}{2} $ and $a=\frac{x^2+9}{2}$.

We should have the following this case.

$x=0$ and $x=\pm x_0$.

Hence, if $x=0$, then the only possible case is $a=\frac{9}{2}$.

Why?

if put $0$ in the first equation in the second case, then you get $a=\frac{23}{2}$ and it implies that $x\geq 4$ and a contradiction. The rest is similar.

Comment: I solved in this way , but in which case it has 3 roots?

Comment: Thank you) But can you explain why the only case is 9/2?

Comment: @VaheMuradyan dzer bari galust akhper

Comment: Where are you from?) Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @VaheMuradyan nai my profile

Comment: but when I put 9/2 instead of a I get 7 roots.+-sqrt(32),0,+-sqrt(14),+-sqrt(18)

Comment: How did you get $\pm\sqrt{18}$ and $\pm\sqrt{14}$ . You can check mentally, they are not root.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $x$ is solution then so is $-x$. So one of the solutions should definitely be $0$, otherwise you would get even number of roots

Answer (score 1):

There is also a simplier, graphical solution to it.

Every time when you plot a graph involving the absolute thing, you can just "flip" the negative region upwards. As you can see in the graph, only when $2a=9$, that is $a=9/2$ will exactly 3 solutions exist.

[image]

This method is typically useful when you are asked to find the no. solution for $y=0$.

Hope it helps.